# Get a condition based select query

Tags: mysql

```
select initial_time, closing_date, length_of_duration(in minutes) from table1;

initial_time is in date time stamp (ex:2011-02-14 20:35:00)
closing_date is in date (for ex:2011-02-14)
length_of_duration in minutes (5)
```

I want to get 0 or 1 (ie true or false) if :

For true:

```
Current time stamp is greater than (initial_time + length_of_duration less than closing_date);
```

For ex: `If current time stamp is 2011-02-14 21:35:00 & initial_time -2011-02-14 20:35:00, length-5 mins and closing date is 2011-02-14, since current time is greater than these, it should return true.`

Any thoughts to get this output based on select query in mysql? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (date_add(initial_time , interval length_of_duration minute)
  <=concat(closing_date, ' 23:59:59'), 1, 0)
```

reason to use `23:59:59` assuming the cut-off date is before 2011-02-15,
which is `2011-02-14 23:59:59`

Comment: Alternatively, the OP could just use ... < (date_add(closing_date, interval 1 day) instead of 23:59:59, which will default the closing date to the next day, starting at midnight.

Comment: not really, the condition is based on number of minutes allowed

Comment: select if ((date_add(initial_time , length_of_duration)<=concat(closing_date, '23:59:59'), 1, 0) from tablename; => I get syntax error, pls. can you help me to get the right syntax.

Comment: `select if (date_add(initial_time , interval length_of_duration minute) <=concat(closing_date, ' 23:59:59'), 1, 0) from tablename;`